# Back and Forward button not working for jquery anchor sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, firefox, google-chrome

Link is here: http://sandbox.brightboxstudios.com/a/

Using a wordpress theme I have changed a bit and I want to add the back and forward button functionality for the anchors..

Firefox shows the anchor in the URL, but chrome doesn't. Neither work for back/forward.

I don't know javascript or jquery, so the more specific the answer, the better!

We're a non-profit, so everything helps! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a "return false" on the click event function that animate the transition between anchors. In this particular case we need to keep the natural behavior of anchors so no need to return false on this event.